# SQL Server Database Publish Profile not using configured property

Tags: sql-server-2012, dacpac, publish-profiles

We have a database project for our SQL Server 2012 database.  This database has a few SQL CLR assemblies which are very rarely updated that I wish to exclude from an automated dacpac deployment.   I created a publish profile with the following settings.

#### Publish Profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetConnectionString></TargetConnectionString>
        <AllowIncompatiblePlatform>True</AllowIncompatiblePlatform>
        <CreateNewDatabase>False</CreateNewDatabase>
        <IgnorePermissions>True</IgnorePermissions>
        <DropObjectsNotInSource>False</DropObjectsNotInSource>
        <IgnoreUserSettingsObjects>True</IgnoreUserSettingsObjects>
        <IgnoreLoginSids>True</IgnoreLoginSids>
        <IgnoreRoleMembership>True</IgnoreRoleMembership>
        <ExcludeObjectTypes>"Assemblies;AsymmetricKeys"</ExcludeObjectTypes>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The most important part of this profile is the tag *ExcludeObjectTypes* which per the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15) should exclude those types from the deployment.  When I try to do a publish in Visual Studio with this profile it is still generating create/alter scripts for the Asymmetric Keys and Assemblies.  How can I exclude these types?

#### Publish Profile Generated Script

```
...
GO
PRINT N'Creating Asymmetric Key [MyKey]...';

GO
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [MyKey]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_1024;

GO
PRINT N'Altering Assembly [MyAssembly]...';

GO
ALTER ASSEMBLY [MyAssembly]
    DROP FILE ALL;
...
```

Comment: Given link is about sqlpackage.exe command-line **syntax** which has nothing to do with publish.xml **format**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for SQL Server 2012 must be different from new versions of SQL Server which are linked in the documentation.  When I opened the profile through the wizard and click *Advanced..* -> Ignore Tab and select *Exclude assembles* and *Exclude asymmetric keys*

[image]

Then it creates entries in the publish profile with the below syntax:

```
    <ExcludeAssemblies>True</ExcludeAssemblies>
    <ExcludeAsymmetricKeys>True</ExcludeAsymmetricKeys>
```

This definition takes effect properly.